# Finding a subgraph of max weight

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, subgraph

I have a city area (let's think of it as a graph of streets), where all streets have some weight and length associated with them. What I want to do is find a connected set of streets, located near other, with some max (or close to max) total weight W, given that my max subgraph can only contain up to N streets.

I'm specifically not interested in a subgraph that would span the entire graph, but rather only a small cluster of streets that has max or close to max combined weight and where all streets are located "near" each other, where "near" would be defined as no street being more than X meters away from the center of the cluster. Resulting subgraph would have to be connected.

Does anyone know if the name for this algorithm assuming it exists?

Also interested in any solutions, exact or approximations.

To show this visually, assume my graph is all the street segments (intersection to intersection) in the image below. So individual street is not Avenue A, it's Avenue A between 10th and 11th, and so on. Street will either have weight of 1 or 0. Assume that the set of streets with max weights are in the selected polygon - what I want to do is find this polygon. 
[image: street network]

Comment: Similatlr problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824344/maximum-edgeweight-connected-subgraph-of-an-undirected-graph (in general, CS- and math-oriented exchanges are better for this kind of questions).

Comment: What does "near" mean in this context? At which weight do i choose the further away street? Is there a function that you try to maximize?

Comment: Near here would be a parameter, but typically within 5 blocks or so. So I'm looking at maybe 2-3 square mile graph of streets, from which I want to pick out maybe 0.5x0.5 (roughly, doesn't have to be square) area of max combined weight

Comment: it seems to me that the graph is a planar graph, is that correct?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic yes, it's a planar graph - basically all the city streets within 3 square miles, with every intersection of the streets as a node, and streets themselves (edges) with weights.

Comment: 'where "near" would be defined as no street being more than X meters away from the center of the cluster. '
I suggest a simple algorithm that pick each node as center and use a shortest path to search for "close street", and return the the cluster with highest weight.
I guess the number of nodes would not be too many, maybe at most 10000? For this data size, the result should be ready within a few secs.
what do you think about it?

Comment: Presumably streets are curves in the plane, so what is "the distance" between two streets?  Is it, for example, the smallest distance between any point on the first street and any point on the second?  I suppose you will say "yes", so the next question is: It is then possible that streets A and B are "close enough", and streets B and C are "close enough", but streets A and C are not "close enough".  Do you require every pair of streets to be "close enough"?  Separately, can we assume that two street vertices are linked by an edge iff those streets intersect?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic that should work, though I in reality I need this to be more real-time, like milliseconds. Do you see any good approximation for that?

Comment: @j_random_hacker the streets here are your normal city streets. So yes, it would be possible that A is close to B, and B is close to C, but A is not close to C if streets are long, and close enough is 100 meters, so it doesn't span more than a street. The metric is not "close enough" between the streets, but close enough to the center of the cluster.

And all intersections here would be vertices - what I call a street is an edge between two intersections. For simplicity, we can assume there are no dead end streets.

Comment: @kozyr: I missed that the criterion was "close enough to the center", sorry, but there is still the issue of what the "center" of a bunch of curve segments (which are your streets) actually is.  (OTOH if you defined things in terms of the center of several points -- e.g., by using intersections -- the meaning of "center" is unambiguous.)  Similarly, I'd still like to know if "the distance between two streets A and B" means "the smallest distance between any point on A and any point on B".

Comment: In any case, I think a reasonable heuristic would be to try placing a radius-X circle at each intersection in turn, extracting the streets that have any point within the circle, and then finding the largest connected component within that subset of streets -- it is likely that the "center of these streets" (however you define that -- see previous comment) is close to the center of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proposal. Consider each vertex in the graph of nodes as the "center" as you've defined it. For each center `C[i]`, execute [Dijkstra's algorithm to construct a shortest path tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) with `C[i]` as the origin. Stop constructing the tree when it would include a vertex more than the max allowed from the center.

Then let `A[i]` be the set of all edges incident to vertices in the tree centered on `V[i]`. The result will be the set `A[i]` with maximum weight.

The run time of one execution of Dijkstra's algorithm is `O(|E[i]| + |V[i]| log |V[i]|)` for the `i`th center. The sets here are limited in size by the max distance from center.  Total cost is `sum_(i in 1..|V|) O(|E[i]| + |V[i]| log |V[i]|)`. In the degenerate case where the max allowable weight allows the whole graph to be included from each center, cost will be `O(|V| (|E| + |V| log |V|))`.

I can think of some possible optimizations to improve run time, but want to verify this gets at the problem you have in mind.

Comment: So this would work, but I don't think it will find the max weight cluster.

Comment: If, let's say, you have a street in the center, and all streets to the left of it have high weight (let's say weights are either 0 or 1 for simplicity, so all streets to the left have weight of 1), then we would have a shortest path that includes, let's say, 10 streets going left with total weight of 10. However, if there are also 10 streets on the right with a weight of 1, those will not be considered, as they are not part of our shortest path. Our max weight here should be 20, but instead will be 10, either from going left or right - assume that our max allowed distance from center is 10 sts

Comment: @kozyr That's as may be, but it's not how you defined the problem. Your words: "where "near" would be defined as no street being more than X meters away from the center"

Comment: well, I used 10 streets here as a metric for simplicity. Assume that each street is 100 meters long, so if we go left 1000 meters (10 streets), and our X (radius) here is 1000, then we have the issue I described - there are 10 more streets that we can include within the right 1000 meters, for max weight of 20 instead of 10.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an integer programming exact formulation for the problem assuming you have a finite number of total streets, S, and the "center" of a cluster can be one of the finite number of streets S. If you are looking at a cluster center in continuous Euclidean space, that is going to take us into the domain of the [Weber Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_problem). That may still be doable, but we would have to look at a [column-generation formulation](http://www.inderscienceonline.com/doi/abs/10.1504/IJOR.2007.012460).

[image]

Objective function maximizes the weight of selected streets indexed by `j`. Constraint (1) specifies that exactly one center be chosen. Constraint (2) specifies that for any potential center, `i`, only `N` streets are chosen as neighbors. Constraint (3) stipulates that a street is chosen as part of some neighborhood only if the corresponding center is chosen. The rest are binary integer constraints.

If the street chosen as center counts as one of the `N` streets, it is easy to enforce by specifying `y_{ii} = x_i`

Note: If the above formulation is right, or captures the problem accurately, [MIP] can be solved trivially, once set `N_i` has been identified.

Consider each `i` in turn. From `N_i` pick the top `N` neighboring streets in descending order of weight. This is your incumbent solution. Update incumbent solution if better solution is found as you iterate through the `i`s.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this solution will return top M streets out of N_i, but there's no guarantee that those streets will be connected. Yes, they are neighbors of i, but the result might end up being two disconnected sets of streets around street i, whereas I'm only interested in connected subset of streets.

Comment: In that case, if every pair of streets in your solution have to be connected, you are looking for the cardinality constrained maximum clique problem. See a paper on that https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~nmegow/papers/ctw09.pdf

Comment: Not every pair though. The result should be a connected graph, but it doesn't have to be fully connected.

Comment: A neighbor of i, N_i, by definition is the set of all nodes connected to i. So, if i is selected, as my original answer indicated, all of the neighbors of i will be connected to each other via i. Can you be more clear about what it means for two streets/nodes to be connected?

Comment: Updated my original question with a picture. 
Regarding the neighbors - neighbor of street_i is any street reachable from street_i, within max distance N. The final set of streets (street_i and its neighbors) should be connected.

Comment: Also, streets are edges, nodes are intersections. For two streets to be connected, they have to have an edge in common. As a result, I want one connected graph of all intersections and streets.